# What is column and row in CSS Grid and what are the differences?

Tags: css, grid, row

What are the differences between rows and columns in [CSS Grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_grid_layout)?

When I look at a Grid Model, it makes sense that the columns flow from left to right across the page and *rows* flow from top to bottom down the page.

Even the number of rows to columns match up and don't appear completely different from the standard definition.

Comment: Have a watch https://youtu.be/8QSqwbSztnA, https://youtu.be/rg7Fvvl3taU and https://youtu.be/_lEkD8IGkwo

Comment: nice explavation and tutorial here: https://www.quackit.com/css/grid/tutorial/css_grid_introduction.cfm

Comment: Thanks for sending those through. I've watched them. The only this is I want to know why columns have such a funny definition. I know how columns and rows work for the most part. I just want to know why columns are defined as running from top to bottom in a vertical line when clearly they break content up into left and middle and right sections

Comment: Pier thanks for sending those through. I agree with the articles explanation but on Codeacademy why does it define Columns and Rows thus?                                                                                   "The column axis stretches from top to bottom across the web page.
The row axis stretches from left to right across the web page. "    W3Schools "The horizontal lines of grid items are called rows"   "The vertical lines of grid items are called columns" This clearly is not the case as the number of Rows to Columns usually does not match up

Comment: Never believe anything W3Schools says. Find a better source of information. MDN is usually reliable.

Comment: Thanks that's really reassuring I was myself for a bit there!